# How to access associate param value in the belongs to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to access rse value which is an Accounts controller strong parameter.
And I'm trying to access it in Tlp controller which is a class that belongs to Accounts. And Accounts belongs to a User.

here is my counsel command that lets me access it.

```
user.accounts.where(id: 13)[0].ase
```

Im very new to rails and i need help translating this command too where i can get that value in my tlp controller.

I know you can create an array then search it but i don't how i would go about creating that array in the tlp controller since it is not directly associated to Users...

Comment: Can you add more info. on what you're trying to do and what you've already done?

Comment: so what I'm trying to do is create a method if i even need a method to calculate an amount that is dependent of how many are is there and an interest rate. but pretty much i I'm trying to use it while creating the tlp.